# NVIDIA GPU throttling? (8800 GTS - card runs super hot)

Tags: nvidia-geforce, throttling

I have an NVIDIA 8800 GTS video card installed in my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit PC. I don't run 3D apps or games all that frequently and as the card runs quite hot I'd like to see if it's possible to set up dynamic GPU throttling.

My computer practically acts as a heater for my office, which while nice in the winter, is unbearable in the summer. If there's a way to make the card run nice and cool while just using desktop apps and then crank up the speed when running a game or what-not that'd be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an older G80-based 8800GTS, your card runs hot and you will need to add case exhaust ventilation below the card, and an additional input fan to provide supply air for balance. I know, I had a well-balanced, cool running system with a G92 based 8800GT and all kinds of overheat problems when I upgraded it to a G80 8800 Ultra. Adding two low case fans, a 120mm in and one 80mm out, fixed the issue.

Please describe your case type and current ventilation (# fans, size, hi or lo speed, position, in or out). Are airflow paths clear or blocked by IDE cables?

Upgrading to a cooler graphics card is a more expensive possibility, you could get an ATi 5770 and improve performance and drop heat.

If you have a G92 based 8800GTS, you may need more case ventilation, but there is some other problem. Are you running Folding@home or SETI@home software on your GPU? What is the ambient room temperature?

If not, your card already has dramatically lower power consumption in 2D mode (Windows desktop, most s/w applications). In that case your card is not making much heat, it is hot because of its environment. If the GPU fan is running high in 2D mode then either the card's fan profile is wrong, which you can adjust with RivaTuner, or your system just runs hot. You can change your fan profile with RivaTuner, but running the fan slower may sound cooler but won't do anything for the case.

You can underclock your GPU with RivaTuner, which will lower power consumption a bit, but won't make much difference in 2D mode as it is already rather low.

Unless you have some background software forcing the card into high power consumption mode, it sounds like you have a case ventilation problem, perhaps complicated by high ambient temperatures.

Answer (score 4):

[RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/rivatuner/) lets you do lots of cool things with nVidia cards.

You could also turn off the Aero effects, and go back to "classic" Windows (I don't remember exactly how it's named in 7 right now).

Answer (score 0):

- on nvidia control panel go to general 3d settings and choose adaptive
  on power management mode.
- turn vsync on if you dont want your gpu to generate more frames than
  necessary.